# Ordering postgres database with ASC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to get my list of skills to be showed in alphabetical order.  I have checked on:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

and am using this line in my Skill.rb model:

```
Skill.order(title: :asc)
```

It does not list them alphabetically and I am guessing I am not putting this line in the right place and I will continue to look into it.

Comment: Actually I think the format is:

Comment: @skills = skill.order('title ASC')

Comment: and I think it goes in the controller=D  Oh yeah worked great! sorry for the silly question!

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix!

in my skill controller where it says

```
@skills = Skill.all
```

for the index action, its done by

```
@skills = Skill.order('title ASC')
```

and bam! easy alphabetically ordered database!
Hope this at least helps someone;)

Comment: Maybe still stick with your hash format. `.order(:title)` or `.order(title: :asc)` if you want to be explicit (since ascending is the default order). Also consider moving this to a scope on your model so that it can be reused.

Comment: Agree with @pdobb, should really go in the model.  Good examples can be found in the [Ruby On Rails Guides - Scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)